# Get web page content to String is very slow

Tags: java, html, bufferedreader

I did the download a web page with the HttpURLConnection.getInputStream() and to get the content to a String, i do the following method:

```
String content="";
isr = new InputStreamReader(pageContent);
br = new BufferedReader(isr);
try {
    do {
            line = br.readLine();
            content += line;
        } while (line != null);
        return content;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        return null;
    }
```

The download of the page is fast, but the processing to get the content to String is very slow. There is another way faster to get the content to a String?

I transform it to String to insert in the database.

Comment: how can the download be fast? you're downloading partially and appending to the string simultaneously.

Comment: pageContent contains the downloaded content like a InputStream. What I done in this code is transform InputStrem in a String.

Comment: getting the content from the `InputStream` is what is called as as downloading.

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes, it's this that makes slow, but...I dont know another way.

Comment: See [read-text-from-inputstream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891606/read-text-from-inputstream#answer-1894244).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read into buffer by number of bytes, not something arbitrary like lines. That alone should be a good start to speeding this up, as the reader will not have to find the line end.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`StringBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) instead.

Edit for an example:

```
StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();

for(int i=0;i<20;++i)
  buffer.append(i.toString());

String result=buffer.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

use the blob/clob to put the content directly into database. 
any specific reason for buliding string line by line and put it in the database??

Comment: Yes, I need get the links the page before I insert into database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jsoup to get specified content of a page and here is a web demo based on jquery and jsoup to catch any content of a web page, you should specify the ID or Class for the page content you need to catch:  http://www.gbin1.com/technology/democenter/20120720jsoupjquerysnatchpage/index.html